# reverse index from string

Tags: python, indexing

For the input text:
I would like to receive following solution:
rafal

"r" 0 -5

---

"a" 1 -4

---

"f" 2 -3

---

"a" 3 -2

---

"l" 4 -1

where first column are letters given in text, second column are indexes values and third column are reverse indexes values.

I performed enumeration:
for idx, znak in enumerate(tekst):
print('"' + znak + '"',  idx)

which gave me following output:
daj tekst:  rafal
"r" 0

---

"a" 1

---

"f" 2

---

"a" 3

---

"l" 4

---

I do not know how to print reverse index values.
When i created new string which was reversion of original text and enumerate through this:

for idx, znak in enumerate(tekst):
new_txt = tekst[::-1]
for r_idx, znak in enumerate(tekst):
print('"' + znak + '"',  idx, r_idx)

I receievd following output:

daj tekst:  rafal
"r" 0 0

---

"a" 0 1

---

"f" 0 2

---

"a" 0 3

---

"l" 0 4

---

"r" 1 0

---

"a" 1 1

---

"f" 1 2

---

"a" 1 3

---

"l" 1 4

---

"r" 2 0

---

"a" 2 1

---

"f" 2 2

---

"a" 2 3

---

"l" 2 4

---

"r" 3 0

---

"a" 3 1

---

"f" 3 2

---

"a" 3 3

---

"l" 3 4

---

"r" 4 0

---

"a" 4 1

---

"f" 4 2

---

"a" 4 3

---

"l" 4 4

---

How can I receive desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```py
def getStringData(string):
  array = list(string)
  length = len(array)
  for index, value in enumerate(array):
    print("'"+value+"'", index, index-length)
getStringData("rafal")
```

##### Output

```
'r' 0 -5
'a' 1 -4
'f' 2 -3
'a' 3 -2
'l' 4 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "rafal"

for i in range(len(word)): 
    print(f"{word[i]}\t{i}\t{i-len(word)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two levels of enumerate, with one of them starting at the first negative index:

```
s = 'rafal'
for n,(i,c) in enumerate(enumerate(s),-len(s)):
    print(repr(c),i,n)

'r' 0 -5
'a' 1 -4
'f' 2 -3
'a' 3 -2
'l' 4 -1
```